# Gulp. Sass (SCSS). Error in plugin

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

There was a problem.
All working and suddenly the error.
http://prntscr.com/ags99q

Many in interenete there is a problem, but could not solve.

Node -v 5.8.0
Npm  -v 3.7.3
Gulp -v 3.9.1

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp         = require("gulp"),
    browserSync  = require("browser-sync"),
    sass         = require("gulp-sass");




gulp.task("watch", ["browser-sync", "sass"], function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.scss", ["sass"]);
});




gulp.task("browser-sync", function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        },
        notify: false
    });
});




gulp.task("sass", function() {
    return gulp.src("src/sass/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of errors.

Comment: Tells you everything you need to know to be able to debug this. `Main.css` is referencing `base/typography` - but `base/typography` (file would likely be `base/_typography.scss`) isn't there.

Comment: All files in place.
The program can work 10 times, then give an error, then work again

Comment: I found the problem.
I work in the last Sublime Text 3.
When you save through it, I have such an error occurs.
I tried to save through the notepad ++.
Sun works fine!
Maybe someone knows where there is a dig?